# Solve for Square Roots

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

> Let $n=pq$, where $p=13710221545914561761$ and $q=11066328760152681859$ are both primes. Find the (two) square roots of $1\bmod n$ that are $\ne\pm1\bmod n$. Let the square roots be $a_1\bmod n$ and $a_2\bmod n$, with $a_1,a_2\in\{0,\dots,n-1\}$, and $a_1>a_2$, find $a_1$.

The problem is related to modular arithmetic involving prime numbers.

Comment: What have you done?

Comment: A flagger indicated that this is from [an ongoing contest](https://www.isical.ac.in/~rcbose/internship/problems2018.pdf). Deleting. Sorry about the inconvenience to the unsuspecting parties.